# Request for member ‘thisWalkno’ in something not a structure or union. (Pthreads)

Tags: c, struct, pthreads

I am trying to get some variables in my struct into another variable in a separate thread but I cant seem to do it. I have a struct like so

```
typedef struct arguments {
      char thisStart[10];
      char thisWalkno[10];
      char thisMatsize[10]; 
      char thisShmkey[10];
      int *pint;
}arguments;
```

Then I have my main, after some initial variable declaration, i start to put my variables in my struct

```
main ( int argc, char argv[]) {
    arguments tid_arg;
    pthread_t tid;
       .    
       .
       .
       .  


    sprintf(tid_arg.thisWalkno,  "%d", (m + 1));  
    sprintf(tid_arg.thisStart,   "%d", start);  
    sprintf(tid_arg.thisMatsize, "%d", matsize);  
    sprintf(tid_arg.thisShmkey,  "%d", shmkey);

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    /* create the thread */
    if (pthread_create(&tid, &attr, tidchild, (void *)&tid_arg) != 0) {
        printf("Could not execute child program\n");
        exit(1);
    } 
     . 
     .
     .
}
```

and finally my tid child function

```
void *tidchild(void *tid_arg) {

    struct arguments *args = tid_arg;
    int walkno, start, shmid, matsize;

    walkno  = atoi(args.thisWalkno);
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

When I get to `walkno  = atoi(args.thisWalkno)`, that's where my error comes, I can't seem to access thisWalkno from the struct. Can anybody help me?

Also I forgot to mention that when I put `args->thisWalkno` I get "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`args` is a pointer to an struct, use `args->thisWalkno` and you should `#include` the `struct` definition wherever you need to use it.

Comment: I tried that too but then I get another error `dereferencing pointer to incomplete type`

Comment: @b1234 Are you declaring your struct in a separate file? if you are then you're not including it, this compiles http://ideone.com/bmJuUw

Comment: Diaz, yes I have my tidchild function in a header file, does that matter?

Comment: @b1234 The compiler has to know what the struct looks like when you're dereferencing that pointer, you should `#include` its definition wherever you need to use it

Comment: It compiled! Thank you.